# How to get list of object by list of ids with BLToolkit?

Tags: mysql, linq-to-sql, bltoolkit

I'm trying to write a code that will be translated into the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM players WHERE Id IN (xxx)
```

With MS-SQL and linq2sql I used "Contains" construction and that worked well.

Now (for MySQl and BLToolkit) I did it this way:

```
    public static IList<Player> GetPlayersByIds(IList<int> ids, DbManager db)
    {
        return db.GetTable<Player>().Where(pl => ids.Contains(pl.Id)).ToList();
    }
```

but the execution of this code returns the following error:

> value(vfm_elita.elita_table.player.Player+<>c__DisplayClass13).ids.Contains(pl.Id)' cannot be converted to SQL.

Is there any solution for this?

If no, how can I query a list of objects by the list of IDs?

Thank you very much, any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I had aged version of BLToolkit that has a bug. After getting 4.1 (that has fully rewritten linq2sql converter) problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Contains in BLToolkit, check the file ..\UnitTests\Linq\Functions.cs
in the BLToolkit sources for some unit-tests using contains

I think (without testing) that the problem with you current code is the use of IList
just try it with a List

```
public static IList<Player> GetPlayersByIds(List<int> ids, DbManager db)
{
    return db.GetTable<Player>().Where(pl => ids.Contains(pl.Id)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I do have a list object type when it is really executed, but thanks for your help.